# Removing trailing /index after removing .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Working on a site which has two versions, one for each language (es,en)
In my root directory I have all the php files for the spanish version, and on subfolder /english/ have all the php files for the english version.

In creating the .htaccess (total newbie at it), wanted to remove the .php extensions so the URL would display nicely. Did some digging around and found this:

```
#Solves Canonical Issue for Main Page
#---------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#---------------------------------------------------------


#Hides .php extensions on pages url´s 
#---------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
#---------------------------------------------------------
```

Which worked fine up to a point. Turns out that if I hit the Home button being on the Spanish version of the site, I´m redirected to www.example.com/index instead of www.example.com. Same happens if I´m on the English version of the site, I get redirected to www.example.com/english/index rather than to www.example.com/english/.

I´m kind of lost. Do I need to use another .htaccess on the /english/ directory and set the RewriteBase as /english/ and then add the same code as above?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]` (backup your code and write this much and check)

Comment: Hey Anant, thanks for your reply. Tried this code and still having the same issue. On clicking the home button Im taken to www.example.com/index (on the spanish version) and to www.example.com/english/index (on the english version)...

Comment: what you want then. you said remove .php extension?

Comment: I want to be able not to show **/index** when being on the homepage on the spanish version nor **/index** when being on the homepage on the english version. As it seems that having www.example.com and www.example.com/**index** will dilute SEO Juice between these two pages, and the same will happen on the english version, having www.example.com/english/ and www.example.com/english/**index**.